# FindBugs does not exclude the filtered patterns with Gradle

Tags: gradle, findbugs

I want to setup the [FindBugsExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html) to [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). It works but I'm unable to exclude specific patterns with the `excludeFilter` option.

I have the following gradle FindBugs definition:

```
findbugs {
    toolVersion = "2.0.1"
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}
```

In the `excludeFilter.xml` I have the following exclude defined:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Bug pattern="NP_PARAMETER_MUST_BE_NONNULL_BUT_MARKED_AS_NULLABLE"/>
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

But when I run `gradle findBugsMain` it fails because it could find FindBugs errors:

```
<BugCollection version="2.0.1" sequence="0" timestamp="1348055542169" analysisTimestamp="1348055545581" release="">
  <!-- ... -->
  <BugInstance type="NP_PARAMETER_MUST_BE_NONNULL_BUT_MARKED_AS_NULLABLE" priority="2" abbrev="NP" category="STYLE">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution from [here](http://issues.gradle.org//browse/GRADLE-2473).

Opposed to the documentation the `excludeFilter` needs to be defined per task due to a [bug](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes#configuration-options-for-findbugs-plugin) in Gradle version 1.2.

So the full configuration would look like this for 1.2:

```
findbugs {
    toolVersion = "2.0.1"
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
}

tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}
```

Comment: It's a known issue that's documented in the [1.2 release notes](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes#configuration-options-for-findbugs-plugin) and has already been fixed for the upcoming 1.3 release.